Android Health connect while reading TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL giving wrong value
We are integrating health connect with read access to calories, heart rate, distance, flight and steps. While testing with latest sdk 1.1.0-alpha07 TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL giving some random value even after deleting all data from health connect app. When we check in AggregationResult it shows data origin for that random number as "_platform".
